# API.AI .NET C# SDK - Parameters appearing as {object}

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm using API.AI and integrating via the .NET SDK for API.AI found in Nuget and using a webhook MVC controller to catch the POST. For passing `string` and `int` data is received fine and saved fine, but if I sent an entity type in API.AI of say @sys.age, the parameter received into the Webook exists as I expect but the value is of type `{object}`. I've tried the following to get the data value out of this `{object}`:-

- `(dynamic)item.Value`
- `item.Value.ToString()`
- `(dynamic)item.Value.ToString()`

where `item.Value` shows {object} in the watch window.

Can anyone suggest how to get the value back from this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you give us more information in your code side.

Comment: I use the API.AI SDK which provides a model called `AIResponse` and you can access the parameters via the following in the webhook

`AIResponse botResponse` --> MVC controller action parameter. The parameters can then be accesssed via `botResponse.Result.Parameters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json of parameters of @sys.age is:

```
"result": {        
        "parameters": {
            "age": {
                "amount": 10,
                "unit": "year"
            }
        },
```

Then you can use classes to capture values in C# like:

```
    public class Age
    {
        public int amount { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
    }
    public class RequestParameter
    {
        public Age age { get; set; }
    }
    public class RequestBody
    {            
        public RequestParameter parameters { get; set; }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetValue(RequestBody result)
    {
        var age = result.parameters.age.amount;
        ...
```

You can see system entities at: https://api.ai/docs/reference/system-entities

Comment: Thanks for this, had a feeling it may be JSON, but I totally missed this section of documentation. +1 and answer.